# Function with throw() mark as incomplete type

Tags: templates, c++17, type-traits

So I have a problem that is ilustrated by the next pieces of code:

A function to test with:

```cpp
int ExampleFunction(int x, int y, double z) throw()
{ 
    return 0;
}
```

I have a template mechanism that extracts the types of the parameters of a function as a tuple:

```cpp
template<typename Func>
struct MyGetFunctionParamType;

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct MyGetFunctionParamType<Ret(Args...)> {
    using types = std::tuple<Args...>;
};
```

Then I used like this:

```cpp
using TypesOfParams = MyGetFunctionParamType<ExampleFunction>::types;
using ThirdParamType = std::tuple_element_t<2, TypesOfParams>;
auto value = ThirdParamType(addrSize(addr));
```

This code used to compile in C++11 but when I try to compile it wiht C++17 I got the `incomplete type is not allowed function "ExampleFunction" is not a type name` error.

I found out that throw was deprecated in C++17 and if I get rid of the `throw()` it compiles, but I was wondering if there is a workaroud to make that compile without explicitly get rid of `throw()`.

Comment: Switch it to `noexcept`? C++17 made noexcept-specifications become part of the function type they appear in. Whereas dynamic exception specifications were mostly removed and remain as not part of the function type. It might be tripping this error. There's little reason to favor `throw()`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica the thing is that the function that I'm trying to actually call is a linux library (exactly socket.h located in /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys) and a bunch of functions there are marked with `throw()`